# Is a company allowed to give employees an option for a bonus to be paid out as a 401k match or cash?

Tags: united-states, 401k, employer-match

Imagine I'm a company with no 401k match. We do offer a sizable cash bonus however.

Some employees are interested in instead receiving this bonus as 401k match (they are currently hitting the $18k IRS maximum through elective deferrals). Presumably for tax reasons.

Am I allowed to give employees the option to elect that a certain percentage of the bonus be paid out as cash or a company 401k match? What do I have to do in order to do this if so?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about company finances and not about personal finance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the type of plan offered: is it a 401(k) plan or a profit-sharing plan, or both?

If it's 401(k) I believe the IRS will see this distribution as elective and count towards the employee's annual elective contribution limit.

If it's profit sharing the distribution would be counted toward the employer's portion of the limit.

However -- profit sharing plans have a formula that's standard across the board and applied to all employees. i.e. 3% of company profits given equally to all employees. One of the benefits of the profit sharing plans is also that you can use a vesting schedule.

I'd consult your accountant to see how this specifically impacts your business - but in the case you describe this sounds like an elective deferral choice by an employee and I don't see how (or why) you'd make this decision for them. Give them the bonus and let them choose how it's paid out.

Edit: in re-reading your question it actually sounds like you're wanting to setup a profit sharing type situation - but again, heed what I said above. You decide the amount of "profit" - but you also have to set an equation that applies across the board. There is more complication to it than this brief explanation and I'd consult your accountant to see how it applies in your situation.

Comment: Ah, I suspect this is one of the differences. In order for it to be a company distribution it would need to be "profit sharing" which it wouldn't be unless it was an evenly applied profit-sharing.

Comment: Indeed. If you're giving a bonus and letting them elect the destination, it's elective and part of their annual limit. If you're giving it to them as profit sharing it's different and under a different annual limit. This is a good long description: https://www.fool.com/knowledge-center/401k-vs-profit-sharing-plans.aspx

Comment: you also might want to read about safe harbor provisions. http://blog.employeefiduciary.com/blog/safe-harbor-401k-plans-answers-to-common-questions

Answer (score 0):

I have worked for companies that have done this. One did have a match and the other did not. When they figured their profit at the end of the year a portion was given to the employees as a 401K deposit.

[retirement-topics-401k-and-profit-sharing-plan-contribution-limits](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-401k-and-profit-sharing-plan-contribution-limits])

> Total annual contributions (annual additions) to all of your accounts
>   in plans maintained by one employer (and any related employer) are
>   limited. The limit applies to the total of:
>
> - elective deferrals
> - employer matching contributions
> - employer nonelective contributions
> - allocations of forfeitures
>
> The annual additions paid to a participant’s account cannot exceed the
>   lesser of:
>
> - 100% of the participant's compensation, or
> - $54,000 ($60,000 including catch-up contributions) for 2017;  $53,000
>     ($59,000 including catch-up contributions) for 2016.

So as long as everything stays below that $54,000 limit you are good.

In one case the decision was made by the company for the employee, the other company gave us the option of bonus check or 401K. I heard that most of the employees wanted the money in the 401K.

Comment: I know that companies can choose to do lump sums, but can they allow their employees to make a decision whether to receive a bonus payment as a cash sum or a 401k? That documentation only talks about the limits for individuals -- not how the 401k plan itself is organized.